# MongoDB: Conditon operators "||" and "&&" returns unexpected result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I’m seeing an unexpected result while querying with “||” and “”&&” conditioning operations.  Looks like this is a bug.

Version:

C:\mongodb\bin>mongo.exe -version
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6

C:\mongodb\bin>
C:\mongodb\bin>mongod.exe -version
db version v2.4.6
Tue Oct 08 16:08:54.073 git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673

Database records:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\mongodb\bin>

>

> db.cars.find()
>   { "_id" : 100, "available" : 1, "color" : "red", "name" : "GTO", "year" : 3939 }
>
> db.cars.find( {available : 1, year : 3939})
>   { "_id" : 100, "available" : 1, "color" : "red", "name" : "GTO", "year" : 3939 }

>

> db.cars.find( { $where: "this.available == 1" && "this.year == 3939" })
>   { "_id" : 100, "available" : 1, "color" : "red", "name" : "GTO", "year" : 3939 }

>
>

> db.cars.find( { $where: "this.available == 1" || "this.year == 3939" })
>   { "_id" : 100, "available" : 1, "color" : "red", "name" : "GTO", "year" : 3939 }

Problem seen:
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

> The below command uses OR condition operation (i.e using || ) and only one condition is true. But still the entry is not displayed.. This is incorrect.
>
> db.cars.find( { $where: "this.available == 11" || "this.year == 3939" })
>
> The below command uses AND condition operation (i.e using && ) and only one condition is true, but entry is displayed which is incorrect. For AND condition both the expression should return TRUE.
>
> db.cars.find( { $where: "this.available == 11" && "this.year == 3939" })
>   { "_id" : 100, "available" : 1, "color" : "red", "name" : "GTO", "year" : 3939 }

Please let me know if I have missed anything.

Regards
Jayanna Hallur
Big Data Analyst,
Wipro Technologies, Bangalore

Answer (score 2):

Your $where statement is incorrect.
It should be a continous javascript string with the logical operator included.

```
"this.available == 1 && this.year == 3939"
```

instead of :

```
"this.available == 1" && "this.year == 3939"
```

A evaluated statement is considered Truthy value.
so consider this:

```
"this.available == 1 && this.year == 3939"  -->   TRUE  && TRUE
 "this.available == 1 || this.year == 3939 || this.favorite == 0" --> TRUE || TRUE || TRUE
```

by having multiple statements, the mongodb interpretor will evaluate statements as per the logical operator,and give results based on last executed statement, so :

> "this.available == 1" && "this.year == 3939"

would return all documents where year = 3939 irrespective of available value.
As && needs all the operands to be checked.

and

> "this.available == 1" ||  "this.year == 3939"

would give all values based on available, and no evaluation of "this.year" takes place.
As || just needs the first true value,and then exits.